# Implementing QTimer to execute a function for a given time

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function that should send data to a raspberry pi for a given period of time depending on the parameter.

```
//headerfiles
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
 QUdpSocket udpSocket;
 // movement Timer
 QTimer* movementTimer;

private slots:
        void sendDatagram(); // Sends to the RaspberryPi
        void processFrameAndUpdateGUI();
        void turnLeft(double time);
        void turnRight(double time);
        void goStraight(double time);
        void MovRobot();

};

// MainWindow.cpp

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        movementTimer = new QTimer(this);
    //send datagram sends data to tehe PI.
        connect(movementTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(sendDatagram()));
       MovRobot(); // MovRobot() function 
    }

   // controls robot to turn left for specified time 

    void TurnLeft(double time)
    {
       s = 1; // sets the value to be sent to the PI.
        movementTimer->setInterval(time);
        movementTimer->setSingleShot(true);
        movementTimer->start();

    } 

//sendDatagram() slot
void MainWindow::sendDatagram() {

    QString datagramOutput = "start," + 
    QString::number(w) + ',' + QString::number(a) + ',' +
    QString::number(s) + ',' + QString::number(d) + ',' +
    QString::number(ui->motorSpeedSlider->value()) + ',' +
    QString::number(dispenserSignal);   
    datagramOutput += ",end";


    QByteArray datagram;
    QDataStream out(&datagram,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out << datagramOutput;
    udpSocket.writeDatagram(datagram,QHostAddress("192.168.0.104"),12345);   
}

//MovRobot  Function;

void MainWindow :: MovRobot() {
if (ui->pushButton_3->isChecked()) {

    MapArea(); // This function maps the area....
    // final_plan is a vector<Point2i> that stores positions on the map for  
    // the robot to move to 

    for (int i = 0; i < final_plan.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = final_plan.size() - 1; j>=0;  j--) {

            do {
                Mat src;
                bool bsuccess = cap.read(src);

                if (!bsuccess) {

                    ui->label_34->setText("Status: Can't read frame.");
                    ui->pushButton_3->setChecked(0);
                }

                GetRobotPosition(src);
                // AngleToGoal calculates the angle of the robot relative 
                // to the final goal.
                double tempAngle = AngletoGoal(final_plan[i][j]);

                if (tempAngle>=0) {
                    turnLeft(TimeToTurn(tempAngle));
                }
                else {
                    turnRight(TimeToTurn(tempAngle));
                }

                double tempDistance = DistancetoGoal(final_plan[i][j]);

                goStraight(tempDistance);

            } while (DistancetoGoal(final_plan[i][j])<20);

        }

    }


}

}
```

The timer should only send the data over to the PI for the duration it in `time`  `sendDatagram` is the function that sends the data over to the Pi. Is there anything I'm missing here. The timer doesn't start inside the `TurnLeft()` function and doesn't run at all. Am I going about this wrong?

EDIT: 13/03/2016:

My apologies for the late reply. I've been quite sick the past few days. I've added the relevant parts of the code. `MovRobot()` is the main function responsible for the movement and this is called in the constructor for MainWindow. I have debugged and stepped through the program and yes, `TurnLeft()` is called. However, the `sendDatagram()` slot doesn't actually send anything in the function. To confirm `sendDatagram()` was actually working, I used another timer to continuously send information to the PI on the robot to control the arm.

```
// Header File
    QTimer* tmrTimer;

   private slot:
    void processFrameAndUpdateGUI();

// MainWindow Constructor:
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
      connect(tmrTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processFrameAndUpdateGUI()));
        tmrTimer->start(10);
}

void MainWindow::processFrameAndUpdateGUI() {

 sendDatagram();

   }
```

The `sendDatagram()` slot is pretty much the same with the exception of me changing what values are being sent to the PI and this seems to work perfectly.

However, my original problem is, I would like to send the data to the robot with for **a specified amount of time** as that makes the robot turn x degrees. This is why I've made `movementTimer()` single shot. 
Stepping through my program, I know this line is called within my `TurnLeft` function.

```
movementTimer->start();
```

but the `sendDatagram()` slot itself doesn't actually send anything to the PI.

Comment: Are you sure `TurnLeft` function executed at all? Show as declaration of `MainWindow` class. Also make sure you call `QApplication::exec()`. Without event loop timer will not work.

Comment: "for a given period of time" => do you mean "*after* a given period of time" ?

Comment: Please post the full code... are you sure `TurnLeft()` is ever called? where `sendDatagram()` is defined? which is its code? has the event loop been started?

Comment: I'd also be curious to see how sendDatagram is declared in the header. is is actually a slot? Also, this is an instance where a few qDebug logs would go a long way.

Comment: @Evgeny Please refer to the edit.

Comment: @Ilya, for a given period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code. The program never called TurnLeft(). So the timer never started. It will be better to start the timer in constrator instead.

Comment: After checking your code, it seems that you try to execute  `sendDatagram()` only one time.
I prefer to do it this way :
1. delete `connect(movementTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(sendDatagram()));`
2. Change all timer function in turnLeft() to :
`QTimer::singleShot(time,this,SLOT(sendDatagram()));`

Answer (score 0):

```
timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(MySlot()));
timer->start(1000);
```

I would try setting the timer to start in the constructor.